# jQuery .load not working on IE (Works fine on all other browsers)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I cannot seem to figure out what's wrong with this code. I've tried just about anything. Both `.load` and `.ready` doesn't fire in Internet Explorer.

Here is a live sample: https://www.assamteacompany.ca/product.php?productid=17657

```
$(function(){
    $('.descr').each(function(){
         var teaAccessory = $('.descr > div').attr('id');
         var description = '_description';      
         $(this).load('https://www.assamteacompany.ca/skin/assam_tea_company/script/product_descriptions.html #' + teaAccessory + description);
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you show us the corresponding HTML?

Comment: https://www.assamteacompany.ca/product.php?productid=17550

Comment: Is there supposed to be a space before the hash?`product_descriptions.html #`

Comment: It's the ID selector for the div I want to insert.

Comment: Please do not post the same question three times using two different SO accounts.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's more reliable to use the document ready event instead of window.load.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // your code
});
```

Or short form:

```
$(function(){
    // your code
});
```

Comment: Coffeescript has an even shorter form `$ ->`

Comment: Doesn't do anything for IE. Both .ready and .load won't load.

Comment: @RodrigoBarraza `.ready` is undefined? Are you sure you are loading jQuery properly?

Comment: @asawyer All other scripts are working fine throughout IE, Chrome, FF, etc.

Comment: @asawyer No, it's not undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Explorer is probably stopping loading of the JavaScript because of one error.

In the Safari console, I am getting the following error, which is likely what's preventing jQuery's JavaScript from running...

> func.js:32ReferenceError: Can't find variable: default_price
>
> func.js:32

Comment: All other scripts are working 100% fine, but let me fix that first to see if it solves anything.

Comment: There's a difference.  The JS for the jQuery loads when the pages loads.  This is blocked from loading because of the error.  This will not stop other JS functions from being called at other times.

Answer (score 0):

Your function check_options() in func.js chokes on `price = default_price;` It does so in both IE and Chrome. Try hard setting it to a number, something like `price = 30;`, to test and see if the code will run. If so, you know that line's the problem.

Different browsers with handle errors differently. In this case, Chrome continues on, while IE stops executing javascript.

Also, on an unrelated note, your version of jquery is old. It's 1.4.2, and they're up to 1.7.1 http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery

Comment: We commented check_options() completely and it didn't change anything. Thanks for the reminder to update but it hasn't fixed the problem.

Comment: @RodrigoBarraza I take it you uncommented it then, cause I went to the site and it's still a problem. Letting it step past that, 'variants' is undefined too, and so is pconf_price, and that's where I stopped. It seems to me you're relying heavily on global variables, and they're not being initialized at the right time. That fact is probably the root of your problem. I strongly recommend against global variables, and this is exactly why.

Comment: Our web developer removed all the buggy variables to see if they were any issue but no go. There's simply so much dirty coding from the previous developers that we've spent the past month cleaning up (slowly) but there's simply still so much left. I'm not the programmer for this project so I try not to worry too much but the backend is even more disgusting then what you've seen.

Comment: @RodrigoBarraza ug, I'm cringing at that thought